# Understanding statistics

Tags: probability, statistical-significance

Speaker on the Christian channel said he read an article that said: "We asked 5000 random women if they experienced domestic abuse; 1,000 said yes." Therefore, the article went on, we predict 1 woman in 5 will experience domestic abuse.
He then said, "Boy, am I steamed because I have 5 daughters!"
Is he correct in lamenting that one of his five daughters is certainly going to experience domestic abuse? Or does his understanding of statistical significance need to be improved? Does he realize that generally speaking, overall. Is he familiar with the 'law of large numbers?'

Is his statement "Boy, I'm steamed" ridiculous and silly?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Is it statistically certain one of his daughters will be abused as he laments?

Comment: In other words, If one in five is assured to beabuse and you have five randon people is it certain one will be abused.

Comment: No. The *expected* number of daughters that will be abused is 1. This is not by any means 'statistically certain'

Comment: A better answer is statistice don't work in reverse. 5000 were checked 1000 experience abuse. Don't tell him "do the math." Tell him the chance of any "particular" person will be abused depends on the risk factors for that person i.e. Was she raised in a Chritian home, doed she attend church frequentlly, socially does she hang out with other christians? Tell him the chance tha any of his daughters being abused is nearly zero.

Comment: That's not a better answer. Ken is correct.

Comment: we can agree to disagree and do it in an agreeable manner. Christian philosophy is Jesus said, "Love your enemy as you much as you love yourself." He also commanded us to "love one another.:

Comment: dankemler - as a teacher of statistics I am sure you point out to your students that statistics are generally speaking. and overall condition, and use the law of large numbers and that around 1 out of every five females experience domestic abuse does NOT mean since a Youth Pastor has five daughters one of them is certain to experience domestic abuse? It just doesn't work that way. Take five particular people you would have to look at the risk factors for them to determine the probability they will be domestically abused.

Comment: If the assumption of 20 % women being abused applies, you can say that for any 5 randomly chosen women is true that: it's 32,77 % probability that none of them experienced abuse; 40,96 % that one did; 20,48 % that two did; 5,12 % that three did, 0,64 % that four did; and 0,03 % that all five of them experienced abuse.

Comment: Problem is we aren't choosing five random people. We are looking at Youth Pastor Jones' five Christian daughters. They were raided in a Christian home by loving mother and father, they attend church regularly, they socially hang out with other Christians whom they will likely marry, Christian philosophy is to be loving and in forgiveness of ones who offends us. So statistics are great, Yes, Pastor Jones 1 in 5 ladies overall, generally speaking in our society experience domestic abuse of some kind but I would feel completely safe in telling Pastor Jones he has nothing to worry about.

Comment: I think you're mixing quite different issues. I wouldn't feel completely safe in advising any Pastor that he or she has nothing to worry about as (a) they should know better than I do whether there is abuse in their family (b) it's not true of any large group that abuse is completely absent.  But a statistical result for a large group can't  be assumed true of every small group included in it. That shouldn't be surprising as a warning and statistics agrees with it. Thus some fair fraction of the population pays to watch sport; I can tell you confidently that no one in my family does that. So?

Comment: I would say his statement "Boy, I'm steamed" is ridiculous for reasons unrelated to statistics

Comment: FYI, "Boy, I'm steamed" is not an idiom I recognise in British English, so it may not be universally clear even to those who have English as their first language.

Comment: @John Jackson, no one on this board except for you has made any claims about certainty. Without knowledge of whether those factors you list increase or decrease the odds of being abused, we can only say this sample leads us to believe that 1 in 5 women experience domestic abuse. Even more so, without knowledge of the sampling procedures used in this study, we can't even say if that 1 in 5 is a reasonable estimate for the population value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the speaker was probably making a joke, playing on the fact that statistical averages **do not** accrue with certainty.  There are plenty of reasons that this conclusion would not accrue statistically.

Even if it is true that 1-in-5 present females experience domestic abuse (and you would want to look a lot more closely at the details of the research before accepting this), the speaker's daughters are not "random women" - they are women with specific characteristics that would make them more or less likely than average to experience domestic abuse (almost certainly *less* likely, given what we know about them just from the question).  Moreover, rates of domestic abuse may also change over their lifetime; since the current trend is downward, one might reasonably expect that trend to continue, so that the probability of even an average woman experiencing domestic abuse might end up being less than the outcome of this point-in-time survey.

Getting a realistic estimate of the probability that a given one of his daughters will experience domestic abuse, would be a difficult exercise.  Even if individual probabilities could be estimated, this would still mean that the number of his daughters that experience domestic abuse will be a random variable with a particular distribution.  Even if the expected value of this distribution is one, this **does not** mean that it is certain that exactly one of his daughters will experience abuse.

Comment: Yes, or poorly expressed his concern over a social issue. Could he expect with certainty that one of his five daughters would experience domestic abuse because that's what statistic says? Of course not,

Comment: Re: "Getting a realistic estimate of the probability that a given one of his daughters will experience domestic abuse, would be a difficult exercise.*  It is only somewhat difficult. 99% of domestic abuse involver someone getting intoxicated. Devout Christians are commanded to love one another, abide with one anoter enventhogh we have differenced and to live quite peaceable lives. Jesus says if are slapped in the face turn the other cheek and say to slap this one as well.

Comment: Ps: My 1st Cousin recently turn 90 and invited everyone over for a "Birthday party." A certain faction of the family informed her their faith prohibited them from attending parties but they would be happy to 'have coffee' at the mall the next morning.